# Per-instance alarms inside auto-scaling groups in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Basically what it ways on the tin, how can I create individual per-instance alarms inside an auto-scaling group created with a CloudFormation template?

I can reference the ASG itself in an alarm and create ASG-level alarms, but cannot seem to specify dimensions to be "any EC2 instance belonging to this ASG".

Is it possible or is my only option user-data script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it thru CloudFormation templates. As you suggested, it will have to be handled thru the user-data script.